# Adding a variable to a variable using +=

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to update `VarA` with the other variables in my code and then print the value of the updated `VarA`.

I get a syntax error for a line of code and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
VarA = VarB
VarA += VarC += VarD
```

I also tried:

```
VarA = 0
VarA += VarB +=VarA += VarC += VarD
```

Note. All other Vars are defined.

Comment: This isn't legal Python syntax. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can do multiple assignment, but not cascaded expressions like this.  The parser is correct: your syntax is illegal; it's not defined in the grammar.  Since you haven't shown what result you expect, we can't "fix" your code.  Follow the posting guidelines: provide a valid example, the result you got (*full* result*) and what you wanted.

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure about the python syntax, but shouldn't it be `VarA += VarB + VarA + VarC + VarD`? Just remove all `=` except the first one, I think that should do it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use += twice on the same line. Instead, try this:

```
VarA = VarB 
VarA += VarC + VarD
```

Using += like above is is equivalent to:

```
VarA = VarA + VarC + VarD
```

Whatever is on the right side gets evaluated and then gets put on the left side.

Comment: Technically the brackets are redundant